# Switch one sandwich column and two columns in responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I tried switching one sandwich column and two columns by using flex. However, I could not do it without using two div tags and display: none;
Could you please give me any advice?

One column image

[image]

Two columns image

[image]

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
 <div class="category1">
   <div class="timezone1">timezone1</div>
   <div class="menu1">menu1</div>
   <div class="timezone2">timezone2</div>
   <div class="menu2">menu2</div>
   <div class="timezone3">timezone3</div>
   <div class="menu3">menu3</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="pc-container">
 <div class="pc-category1">
   <div class="pc-timezone1">timezone1</div>
   <div class="pc-timezone2">timezone2</div>
   <div class="pc-timezone3">timezone3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="pc-category2">
   <div class="pc-menu1">menu1</div>
   <div class="pc-menu2">menu2</div>
   <div class="pc-menu3">menu3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.pc-container {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){

  .container {
    display: none;
  }

  .pc-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}
```

These images are added July 28.

Initial screen
[image]

Narrow to show smartphone screen

[image]

Re-large to show PC screen, but each column is not side by side.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch from columns to wrapping rows....

```css
.category1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .5em;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .category1 {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .category1 > div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
  }
  .category1 > [class^="menu"] {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="category1">
    <div class="timezone1">timezone1</div>
    <div class="menu1">menu1</div>
    <div class="timezone2">timezone2</div>
    <div class="menu2">menu2</div>
    <div class="timezone3">timezone3</div>
    <div class="menu3">menu3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GqGEGW?editors=1100)

Comment: Thank for posting your idea. Then, I checked changing to the design I aimed. Thanks lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/LkALXG/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="timezone">timezone1</div>
  <div class="menu">menu1</div>

  <div class="timezone">timezone2</div>
  <div class="menu">menu2</div>

  <div class="timezone">timezone3</div>
  <div class="menu">menu3</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.timezone,
.menu{
  width:50vw;
  display:inline-block;
}

.menu{
  float:right;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .menu,
  .timezone{
   float:none;
   display:block; 
   width:auto;
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for posting your two ideas. But I am afraid I checked these did not work.  For example, http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/LkALXG/, I try reducing and extend the window width for checking smartphone and PC screen. As a result I checked each two columns are not located horizontally.

Comment: Hi @hikozuma, thanks for your feedback. If http://s.codepen.io/panchroma/debug/LkALXG doesn't work for you when you change the window width, could you please let me know what browser you are using?  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. For me at viewports above 767px the timezone and menu columns are side by side, and on narrower screens it collapses to one column with the timezone and menu items alternating.

Comment: Sure, @david-taiaroa. I use Google Chrome and its version is  51.0.2704.103 (64-bit). Then, your way of thinking is right. It is hard to express the issue, I will add screen shots. Please check them later.

Comment: thanks for adding your screenshots @hikozuma. I get a different result from you with Chrome on Mac, I'm reasonably sure the reason it isn't looking great for you is related to default browser styling. I'm using normalize in my codepen example and usually that will fix this, but I guess not in this caae. See if http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/xOJKxL is any better for you, I changed the desktop column widths from 50vw to 50%. If that still doesn't work, decrease this value a little.  Good luck ;)